# Adding a new column in a data.table with information from another data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm analyzing multiple data.table's in R using the data.table package and am struggling with pulling information from multiple tables at a time.

I have a `products` data.table and a `january_views` data.table. The `january_views` table lists the `customer_id`, `product_id`, and `time`. In the products table, it lists the `product_id`, `category`, and `price`. I want to create a table that lists the most viewed products that will include the `product_id`, the `category`, and the number of views.

I've been able to create a table that shows the amount of times the products were viewed in descending order from the january_views table but I don't know how to add in the category from the products table. This is what I have so far:

```
tab <- january_views[, .N, by = product_id]
setorderv(tab, cols = "N", order = -1)
```

How can I add in the category to this table?

Here's reproducible data for both data.tables:

```
structure(list(category = structure(c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), levels = c("coat", "hat", "pants", "shirt", 
"shoes"), class = "factor"), product_id = c("dCgYSwwE8gjlmm7u", 
"GyoBFMLpSxMyYNXJ", "LJFl3aX0EUW84u06", "SIKFeFci7HLldbiL", "qFBRZdMfS00mk0x8", 
"5S0HofP6wP7TXQbm", "t3qGXTgA4SvSq92B", "IMWN7BvRKgXkMMNy", "AinHMrbMn8ygQnjq", 
"SuLEtq5M9tTAFPYP"), price = c(122.19, 128.99, 110.99, 137.99, 
112.99, 114.99, 114.99, 154.1, 116.99, 129.79)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x1488180e0>)

structure(list(customer_id = c("S4PpjV8AgTBx", "p5bpA9itlILN", 
"nujcp24ULuxD", "cFV46KwexXoE"), product_id = c("kq4dNGB9NzwbwmiE", 
"FQjLaJ4B76h0l1dM", "pCl1B4XF0iRBUuGt", "e5DN2VOdpiH1Cqg3"), 
    time = structure(c(1577872800.28324, 1577872800.89588, 1577872801.36233, 
    1577872801.87305), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "America/New_York")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x1488180e0>)
```

Comment: Can you show what the resulting frame looks like? What are the new values? It's not clear this is just a merge, a merge-with-aggregation, or something else. Thanks!

Comment: Try `january_views[products, .(category, .N), on = .(product_id), by = .EACHI]`